# ¿Cómo eliminar una línea de texto que contiene números?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Tengo un archivo `.str` que se usa para los subtítulos de películas. Mi problema es que no puedo eliminar las lineas de texto que contienen los tiempos, para poder dejar solamente los diálogos.

**Por ejemplo:**

> 427
>   00:39:50,594 --> 00:39:55,499
>   Nos maravillamos de nuestra
>   magnificencia cuando dimos vida a I.A.
>   428
>   00:39:55,908 --> 00:39:57,319
>   ¿I.A.?
>   429
>   00:39:58,020 --> 00:39:59,555
>   ¿Inteligencia artificial?

**Y que quede de esta forma en un nuevo archivo:**

> Nos maravillamos de nuestra
>   magnificencia cuando dimos vida a I.A.
>   I.A.?
>   ¿Inteligencia artificial?

Si alguno sabe una forma utilizando métodos de Python como **`str.isdigit()`** (el cual no me funcionó) o similares  para que verifique cada linea, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más sencillo en este caso es utilizar expresiones regulares, usando una expresión regular en la que encajen sólo números y ciertos símbolos que aparecen en las marcas de tiempo (`:`, `,`, `-`, `>`) de modo que todas las líneas que encajen en esa expresión regular sean descartadas.

Es decir (en este ejemplo, para que la respuesta sea autocontenida, en lugar de un fichero uso una cadena para contener el texto, la cual abro como si se tratara de un fichero mediante `io.StringIO(cadena)`. En tu caso debes poner en su lugar `open(nombre_fichero)`):

```
fichero = """\
427
00:39:50,594 --> 00:39:55,499
Nos maravillamos de nuestra
magnificencia cuando dimos vida a I.A.
428
00:39:55,908 --> 00:39:57,319
¿I.A.?
429
00:39:58,020 --> 00:39:59,555
¿Inteligencia artificial?
"""

import io
import re

resultado = []

with io.StringIO(fichero) as f:
  for linea in f:
    if re.match("^[0-9:,-> ]+$", linea):
      continue
    resultado.append(linea)

print("".join(resultado))
```

```
Nos maravillamos de nuestra
magnificencia cuando dimos vida a I.A.
¿I.A.?
¿Inteligencia artificial?
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta y tu tiempo. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

`str.isdigit` no te funciona porque solo retorna `True` si **toda la cadena son dígitos** y tu necesitas que retorne `True` si hay al menos un dígito en principio. Para ello puedes recorrer la cadena y aplicar `str.isdigit` sobre cada carácter:

```
with open("input.str", "r") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile: 
    for line in infile:
        if not any(c.isdigit() for c in line):
            outfile.write(line)
```

No obstante si uno de los diálogos tiene un dígito tenemos un problema. En este caso mejor usar una expresión regular como muestra @abulafia en su respuesta. Otra opción diferente es usar `re.sub`.

En vez de ir linea a linea, dado que aparentemente las lineas a eliminar van juntas, es decir una línea con solo un número seguida de otra con el intervalo de tiempo podemos capturarlas como bloque, de forma que si existe la posibilidad de que una línea de diálogo sea solo un número no sea eliminada:

```
import re


patt = re.compile(r'^\d+[\r\n]+\d{2}:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\,\d{3}\s\-{2}>\s\d{2}:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\,\d{3}[\r\n]+',
                  flags=re.MULTILINE
                  )
with open("input.str", "r")  as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(re.sub(patt, "", infile.read()))
```

La expresión regular es bastante simple:

- **`^`**: coincidencia después de una nueva línea
- **`\d+`**: coincidencia con conjunto de uno o más dígitos
- **`\d{2}`**: coincidencia con dos dígitos
- **`[\r\n]+`**: coincidencia con cualquier número de caracteres `\r` o `\n` (nueva línea)
- **`[0-5]`**: coincidencia con un dígito en el rango 0 a 5.
- **`\s`**: espacio

Por ejemplo para un archivo original:

> 427
>   00:39:50,594 --> 00:39:55,499
>   ¿Qué edad tiene?
>   428
>   00:39:55,908 --> 00:39:57,319
>   17
>   429
>   00:39:58,020 --> 00:39:59,555
>   Pues parece mayor

Obtendremos:

> ¿Qué edad tiene?
>   17
>   Pues parece mayor

Esto tiene una contrapartida, es más agresivo con el uso de RAM al cargar en memoria el fichero completo en vez de iterar linea a linea.

Comment: Gracias por tu solución y tu tiempo invertido en ayudar. Muy útil cada palabra que enunciaste